# How do you customize dispatches in React Redux containers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The way React Redux is built requires you to dispatch changes from within the `mapDispatchToProps()` function. If I want to use the container (the higher order component that connects a React component to Redux) to access state, while, at the same time being able to dispatch different actions *(depending on the feature), I either:

1. need to add all the ways of dispatching for all features to the `mapDispatchToProps()` function of the container that is accessing state
2. need to create an additional container for each feature to wrap the container that is accessing state
3. need to expose `dispatch()` to the feature through a callback prop

Is there a recommended implementation to customize which actions are dispatched that isn't in the list above? **Specifically, why would option number three be a bad choice?**

**Example Use-case**

I have a React presentational component (VerticalBarChart) and a React-Redux container component (VerticalBarChartContainer). I want to access data from the same location in state but need to handle when users click on the chart's bars differently (depending on the feature). In Feature A, I want my feature to act as if I have drilled into the data for that bar, in Feature B I just want to display more details about that bar's data in a modal.

**Example 1 (all variations of dispatch inside of `mapDispatchToProps()`)**

```
<!-- Feature A -->
<VerticalBarChartContainer bar-click-action="drill" />

<!-- Feature B -->
<VerticalBarChartContainer bar-click-action="showDetailsModal" />
```

**Example 2 (wrapping the container in each feature)**

```
<!-- Feature A (contains a VerticalBarChartContainer) -->
<FeatureAVerticalBarChartContainer />

<!-- Feature B (contains a VerticalBarChartContainer) -->
<FeatureBVerticalBarChartContainer />
```

**Example 3 (exposing dispatch)**

```
<!-- Feature A -->
<VerticalBarChartContainer 
   onBarClick={ (dispatch) => dispatch(action1()) } 
   />

<!-- Feature B -->
<VerticalBarChartContainer 
   onBarClick={ (dispatch) => dispatch(action2()) }
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is that a container should rarely contain JSX or define a component itself, rather it should just wrap inner components with HoCs. On that basis I think a good pattern is to fork the behaviour by creating multiple different containers all wrapping the same inner presentational component, which I think is your example 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dispatch an action conditional on state and/or props, you can do so through the `mergeProps` method, the third argument to `connect`.  The `mergeProps` method receives state props (object returned from `mapStateToProps`), dispatch props (object returned from `mapDispatchToProps`), and the component props.

Here is an example usage (please not mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps methods are omitted since I assume you're familiar):

```
function mergeProps(stateProps = {}, dispatchProps = {}, ownProps = {}) {
  const { conditionA } = ownProps;
  const { conditionB } = stateProps;
  const { firstFn, secondFn } = dispatchProps;
  const onClick = (conditionA && conditionB) ? firstFn : secondFn;

  return {
    ...ownProps,
    ...dispatchProps,
    ...stateProps,
    onClick,
  };
}

export const ConnectedComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  mergeProps,
)(Component);
```